# dealing with the error 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require'

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require, module.exports

I feel like I am doing the most vanilla thing ever but for some reason it is not working. I am using Nodejs. I am trying to import multiple functions and here is how I am doing it. I would love any advice to steer me in the right direction!

Exports

```
exports.generateInputs = generateInputs;
exports.changeToRestartText = changeToRestartText;
exports.generateRanNum = generateRanNum;
exports.inputsList = inputsList;
exports.startButton = startButton;
```

Imports

```
const startLogic = require('./startButton')
```

The following usage of the imported functions

```
startLogic.startButton.onclick = () => {
    const ranNum = startLogic.generateRanNum();
    startLogic.generateInputs(ranNum)
    startLogic.changeToRestartText()
}
```

Comment: Button onclick? You know there are no buttons and no onclick DOM events in Nodejs, right?

Comment: Or, if you're running this code in the browser, there is no `require()` in the browser.

Comment: Generally speaking, the importing module name is the same as the file name. For example, if you import path, you'd do const path = require('path').  Also, require means you're importing a different module with proper module.exports declarations.  And it's obvious what you have there has no declarations... as it's NOT written for Node.js...  So, I am curious what exactly are you writing... Was it really for node, or just JS?

Comment: I think the poster reposted the question and stated he's using jsdom in Node.js or something like that. Can we merge this with that other question or close this?